# My keyboard doesn't have a Linux driver, can someone tell me what these error messages mean?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

This question may be better asked on unix.stackexchange.com, but I'm asking it here because I'm quite sure someone will have an answer.

My keybaord doesn't have a driver for Linux, and I'm thinking about trying to write one as a way to learn C. I have a book but a good project is also helpful. I don't really know how to go about doing that, but thats a question for another place and time. The question I have now is what do the following error messages mean?

I get 54 of these on boot, each with a different leading number in the brackets.

`[    1.543402] hid-generic 0003:05C7:2012.0004: unknown main item tag 0x0`

and then I get 1 of these:

`[    1.546827] hid-generic 0003:05C7:2012.0004: unbalanced collection at end of report description`

and 1 of these :

`[    1.547479] hid-generic: probe of 0003:05C7:2012.0004 failed with error -22`

Can someone tell me what these mean? I know for a fact it's my keyboard. The messages go away when I unplug it.

Comment: You might find useful information regarding the probe error here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199827/linux-usb-device-driver-not-getting-probed. Depending on your programming experience, learning C by developing a Linux driver is going to be tough. I recommend learning the basics of C in userland, then move to driver development.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for spoiling your fun, but it does not sound like a good project. For one thing, there is [this Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1385113) which sounds very similar to yours indeed. Second, there is a possible solution [on the ever helpful Arch Linux wiki](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=181633): it is recommended that you enable `EHCI Hand-off` in your BIOS settings.

If it is indeed a bug, or a misconfiguration of the BIOS settings, it is hardly a matter to be solved by writing a good driver. My personal inclination is that it is a matter of BIOS setting (will you let me know?) because [this German fellow](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-de/2006-October/006396.html) reports using exactly your generic keyboard without a hitch in 2006. He displays the output of

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices
.......
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=05c7 Product=2012 Version=0001
N: Name="Generic USB K/B"
```

which is exactly your keyboard as reported by

```
[    1.543402] hid-generic 0003:05C7:2012.0004: unknown main item tag 0x0
```

As for the meaning of the error messages, I can help you only partially: [hid-generic](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hid/hid-generic.c) is a driver for HID-compatible peripherals. HID (=Human Interface Device) is a protocol for the specification of input/output devices assuring compatibility of components across different computers. You can find a good intro to HID [here](http://generichid.sourceforge.net/).

You were searching for an (advanced!) C project: you may then hunt down the error messages you find in the code of the `hid-generic` driver I referenced above. I am too lazy to do it myself.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I looked in my BIOS and didn't find that option. I'm going to do some googling, but I'm wondering if my ASROCK bios doesn't have that option. If not, I can live with the errors.